# when doing ignite scaffold :> exec: "go": executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: tendermint, cosmos-sdk, starport

I am on ubuntu and installed go in path as well.

go version print the version

echo $PATH shows both GOPATH and go exec in path.

but when I run: sudo ignite scaffold chain github.com/alice/checkers

I get:

: exec: "go": executable file not found in $PATH

Answer (score 0):

Are those environment variables exported?  Perhaps you're forking a new shell and the variables aren't in scope because you didn't do "export PATH=..."